# Itô's formula for an expectation result

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, chain-rule, stochastic-differential-equations

I applied Itô's formula to $f(x)=x^q$ for $q>1$ with a process defined by the SDE
\begin{align*}
dX_t = \mu(t,X_t)dt + \sigma(t,X_t) dW_s,
\end{align*}
where $W_s$ is a Brownian motion, $\mu(t,X_t)$ is the drift, which obeys the growth condition $\mu(t,x)\leq C (1+|x|)$, for some constant C>0, and $|\sigma|$ is bounded.

Now, assuming that we look at $X_t$ up to the first hitting time of $X_t=0$, $f\in\mathcal{C}^2(\mathbb{R}_+)$ so Itô can be applied, i.e.
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X_t^q]=\mathbb{E}[\int_0^t qX_s^{q-1}dX_s]+\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t(q-1)qX_s^{q-2}d[X]_s],
\end{align*}

where $[X]_s$ is the sharp bracket of $X_t$. I'd like to deduce that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X_t^q]=c\cdot\mathbb{E}[\int_0^t X_s^qds],
\end{align*}
for some constant $c>0$.

Comment: why should it be true ?

Comment: For $q\in(1,2)$, you have $f\notin C^2$.

Comment: @user10354138 I edited it.

Comment: @Surb I don't know if it's true and I can't deduce it myself, that's why i asked for help in either proving or finding a counterexample.

Comment: This would essentially imply $\mathbb{E}[X_{t}^{q}]=e^{ct}$. That's too much to hope for, I think.